# MVC3 using jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and $("#form").submit() hijax not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I have a basic form

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" }))
{
     <div class="editor-label">
         <label for="Name">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</label>
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
     </div>
```

and so on. My Model is using data annotations and validation is turned on.

I'm hijaxing the form using some jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form[action='/']").submit(function () {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
            $("#contactForm").replaceWith($("#contactForm", response));
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

This works if I type the fields in correctly and submit. But the strange thing is if I enter an invalid value into one of the form fields and the validation code kicks in to highlight my mistake the submit event function I appended in the hijaxing script above is lost and a full post happens.

Any good ideas as to how I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think when you add a submit handler to your form you are overwriting the submit handler that the jquery validation / data annotations adds.

To get around this you can add:

```
var theForm = $(this);
if ( theForm.valid() ) {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
        $("#contactForm").replaceWith($("#contactForm", response));
    });
    return false;
}
```

This will make sure the form is valid before making the POST.

Comment: Thanks. That does seem to be the issue.

Comment: @Dismissile Im not seeing where you are hooking the submit? im prob just missing something, been a long day : )

Comment: @AdamTuliper the code Dismissile gave is in addition to what Tom Miller already had.